# Google OK (Now) integration with our app not working

Tags: voice-recognition

We setup Google OK (Google Now) with my app success fully integrate with [this](https://antonioleiva.com/voice_search_google_now/)

example.

in example, its says "App must be uploaded on play store" or you can test using adb command.

So may app work with command, but in some device(not all device) also work with "google now".

My requirement is , when user launch "Google Now" and speak like "Total amount of site number 117 in 2017 on "App name" then my app is open.

Here my app is not open directly search in search bar.

So what's problem here.

Note: My app is not available in play store yet.

Comment: share code if you need help

Comment: Please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.